# How to receive a file from java to C via tcp/ip?

Tags: java, c, sockets, unix, tcp

I have to send a file to java, and java has to receive the file and send it back to C via tcp/ip. I am able to send the file but in receiving i am not able to receive any data. I am giving the code for reference.

```
int send_text(int socket)
{
    FILE *text;
    char a[50];
    int size, read_size, stat, packet_index;
    char send_buffer[8008], read_buffer[8008];
    int wrt = 0, sock_fd, tsize = 0;
    packet_index = 1;
    int i = 0;
    text = fopen("/home/sosdt009/Desktop/character3.txt", "r");
    if (text == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error Opening text File:");
        exit(-1);
    }

    printf("Getting text Size:\n");
    gets(a);
    fseek(text, 0, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(text);
    fseek(text, 0, SEEK_SET);
    printf("Total text size: %d \n", size);
    gets(a);

    //Send text Size
    printf("Sending text Size:\n");
    gets(a);
    send(socket, (void *) &size, sizeof(size), 0);
    while (size > tsize)
    {

        //Read from the file into our send buffer
        printf("Ready for sending:\n");
        gets(a);
        read_size = fread(send_buffer, 1, sizeof(send_buffer), text);
        printf("The size of send buffer:%c \n", sizeof(send_buffer));
        gets(a);
        printf("The read size value is :%d \n", read_size);
        gets(a);

        //Send data through our socket      
        for (i = 0; i < read_size; i++)
        {
            printf("Send value: %c \n", send_buffer[i]);
            gets(a);
        }

        do
        {
            stat = send(socket, send_buffer, read_size, 0);
            printf("The send size value is: %d \n", size);
            gets(a);
            printf("The read size value is: %d \n", read_size);
            gets(a);
        }
        while (stat < 0);

        printf("Packet %d, sent %d bytes.\n", packet_index, read_size);
        gets(a);

        //packet_index++;
        //Zero out our send buffer

        tsize = tsize + read_size;
        printf("The tsize value is:%d \n", tsize);
        gets(a);
        memset(send_buffer, 0, sizeof(send_buffer));

        if (read_size <= NULL)
        {
            printf("The connection is transferred to received text: \n");
            gets(a);
        }
    }

    fclose(text);
    printf("Text successfully send:\n");
    gets(a);

    return 0;
}

int receive_text(int socket)
{
    int buffersize, recv_size = 0, read_size = 1, write_size, size, stat;
    char *pBuf, a[50];
    int errno,i;
    FILE *text;
    text = fopen("/home/sosdt009/Desktop/receivednew.txt", "a");
    if (text == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error has occurred, text file could not be opened \n");
        return -1;
    }

    //Loop while we have not received the entire file yet
    while (read_size > 0)
    {
        ioctl(socket, FIONREAD, &buffersize);
        printf("The Buffersize is    :%d\n", buffersize);
        gets(a);
        printf("The size of socket is:%d\n", socket);
        gets(a);

        //We check to see if there is data to be read from the socket 
        if (buffersize > 0)
        {
            printf("Buffersize value is  :%d\n", buffersize);
            gets(a);
            pBuf = malloc(buffersize);
            if (!pBuf)
            {
                printf(errno, "Memory Error Cannot Allocate!\n");
                gets(a);
                exit(-1);
            }

            read_size = recv(socket, pBuf, buffersize, 0);
            printf("Read size value is :%d \n", read_size);
            gets(a);
            printf("Buffersize value is:%d \n", pBuf);
            gets(a);
            if (read_size < 0)
            {
                printf("%d\n", strerror(errno));
                printf("Data not written to the file:\n");
                gets(a);
                goto free;
            }

            //Write the currently read data into our text file
            write_size = fwrite(pBuf, 1, read_size, text);
            free(pBuf);
            printf("Write size value is   :%d \n", write_size);
            gets(a);
            printf("Buffer size value is  :%d \n", buffersize);
            gets(a);

            //Increment the total number of bytes read          
            recv_size += read_size;
            printf("Received size value is:%d \n", recv_size);
            gets(a);
            printf("Read size value is    :%d \n", read_size);
            gets(a);
        }
    }
    free: fclose(text);
    close(socket);
    printf("Text Successfully Received:\n");
    gets(a);

    return 0;
}
```

Adding the java code for further ref

```
  import java.io.File;
  import java.io.FileInputStream;
  import java.io.FileOutputStream;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.io.InputStream;
  import java.io.OutputStream;
  import java.net.ServerSocket;
  import java.net.Socket;
  public class Server1 {
  static ServerSocket serverSocket =null;
  private static Socket socket;
  public final static String FILE_TO_RECEIVED =   "/home/sosdt010/Desktop/Testfile/text2.txt";
  public final static int FILE_SIZE = 32092796 ;//4939993 ;//
  static int current=0;
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,    InterruptedException {
  int port = 6777;
  serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
  System.out.println("Server Started and listening to the port 6777");
  socket = serverSocket.accept();
  InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
  //ois=new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
  //byte[] content = (byte[]) ois.readObject();
  FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(FILE_TO_RECEIVED );
  System.out.println(FILE_TO_RECEIVED);
  byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [FILE_SIZE];
  //  int bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
  // System.out.println(mybytearray.length);
  //current = bytesRead;
  //System.out.println(current+"/n"+bytesRead);
  int bytesRead;
   do {
         bytesRead =
         is.read(mybytearray, 0,mybytearray.length-current);

         if(bytesRead >= 0) current += bytesRead;
         System.out.println(bytesRead );

      } while(bytesRead > -1);
         for(int a=0;a<current;a++){
         fos.write(mybytearray[a]);
      }
          System.out.println(current +"new bytesread"+mybytearray.length);
      //fos.write(mybytearray, 0,current);
      System.out.println("Message received from server is "+current);


      OutputStream os=socket.getOutputStream();
      File myFile=new File(FILE_TO_RECEIVED);
      System.out.println(FILE_TO_RECEIVED);
      FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(myFile);
      byte[] mybytearray1=new byte[(int)myFile.length()];
      System.out.println(myFile.length());
      fis.read(mybytearray1, 0, mybytearray1.length);
      System.out.println("Bytes Read"+ mybytearray1.length);
      os.write(mybytearray1, 0, mybytearray1.length);
      System.out.println("Bytes write"+mybytearray1.length);
      System.out.println(mybytearray1.length);
      // byte[] content1 = Files.readAllBytes(new              File(FILE_TO_SEND).toPath());
      //oos.writeObject(content1);
       os.flush();

       fos.close();
       is.close();
       //fis.close();
       //os.close();
       socket.close();
    }
  }
```

I am giving the Receiving code that i am currently using in the program

```
    int receive_text(int socket)
{ 
    int buffersize[8192],recv_size = 0,read_size = 1, write_size, size; 
    char *pBuf,a[50]; 
    int errno;
    FILE *text; 
    text = fopen("/home/sosdt009/Desktop/receivednew.txt", "w");    
    if (text == NULL)   
    {       
        printf("Error has occurred, text file could not be opened \n");
        return -1;
    }

     //Loop while we have not received the entire file yet

      while (read_size > 0)
     {          
        ioctl(socket, FIONREAD, &buffersize);
        printf("The Buffersize is    :%d\n",buffersize);
        gets(a);
        printf("The size of socket is:%d\n",socket);
        gets(a);

        //We check to see if there is data to be read from the socket 

    if (buffersize > 0)
    {
        printf("Buffersize value is  :%d\n", buffersize);
        gets(a);
        pBuf = malloc(buffersize);
        /*if (!pBuf)
        {
            printf(errno, "Memory Error Cannot Allocate!\n");
            gets(a);
            exit(-1);
        }*/
             while ((read_size = recv(socket, buffersize, sizeof(buffersize), 0)) > 0)
        {
            fwrite(pBuf, 1, read_size, text); // plus error handling ...
        }

        //read_size = recv(socket, pBuf, buffersize, 0);
        //printf("Read size value is :%d \n",read_size);
        //gets(a);
        //printf("Buffersize value is:%d \n",pBuf);
        //gets(a);

        if (read_size < 0)
        {
            printf("%d\n",strerror(errno));
            printf("Data not written to the file:\n");
            gets(a);
            goto free;
        }

        //Write the currently read data into our text file

        write_size = fwrite(pBuf,read_size,1,text); 
        free(pBuf);
        printf("Write size value is   :%d \n",write_size);
        gets(a);
        printf("Buffer size value is  :%d \n",buffersize);
        gets(a);

        //Increment the total number of bytes read

        recv_size += read_size;
        printf("Received size value is:%d \n",recv_size);
        gets(a);
        printf("Read size value is    :%d \n",read_size);       
        gets(a);            
      }
    }
     free:
     fclose(text);
     close(socket);     
     printf("Text Successfully Received:\n");
     gets(a);
     return 0;
 }
```

I am putting the code according to your modification

```
 int receive_text(int socket)
 { 
     int buffersize[8192],recv_size = 0,read_size=1, write_size, size; 
     char *pBuf,a[50]; 
     int errno;
     FILE *text; 
     text = fopen("/home/sosdt009/Desktop/receivednew.txt", "a");   
     if (text == NULL)  
     {      
         printf("Error has occurred, text file could not be opened \n");
         return -1;
     }

     //Loop while we have not received the entire file yet

      while (read_size > 0)
      {     
             while ((read_size = recv(socket, buffersize, sizeof(buffersize), 0)) > 0)
        {
            fwrite(pBuf, read_size, 1, text); // plus error handling ...
            printf("Write size value is   :%d \n",write_size);
            gets(a);
            printf("Buffer size value is  :%d \n",buffersize);
            gets(a);
        }
        //while (!buffersize && ioctl (socket,FIONREAD,&buffersize) >= 0)
            //ioctl(socket, FIONREAD, &buffersize);
        //printf("The Buffersize is  :%d\n",socket);
        //gets(a);

       //We check to see if there is data to be read from the socket 

       //if (buffersize > 0)
         //{
        //printf("Buffersize value is  :%d\n", buffersize);
        //gets(a);

        //pBuf = malloc(buffersize);
        if (!pBuf)
        {
            printf(errno, "Memory Error Cannot Allocate!\n");
            gets(a);
            exit(-1);
        }


        //read_size = recv(socket, pBuf, buffersize, 0);
        //printf("Read size value is :%d \n",read_size);
        //gets(a);
        //printf("Buffersize value is:%d \n",pBuf);
        //gets(a);

        if (read_size < 0)
        {
            printf("%d\n",strerror(errno));
            printf("Data not written to the file:\n");
            gets(a);
            goto free;
        }

        //Write the currently read data into our text file

        write_size = fwrite(pBuf,read_size,1,text); 
        free(pBuf);
        //

        //Increment the total number of bytes read

        recv_size += read_size;
        printf("Received size value is:%d \n",recv_size);
        gets(a);
        printf("Read size value is    :%d \n",read_size);       
        gets(a);            
    //}
     }
     free:
     fclose(text);
     close(socket);     
     printf("Text Successfully Received:\n");
     gets(a);
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: What sort of a file is it? Do you need only the contents or the file itself?

Comment: If you have problems with the Java side of your code, how can we help you solve them if you're only showing the C side?

Comment: Could the problem belongs to the java sender? Could you post it?

Comment: I am sending a text file with some characters in it,i have to receive the same characters in receiving side also and there is no problem in java because i have already verified with my friends.

Comment: I am adding java code for further reference

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but how about just using ftp and not reinventing the wheel? There are clients available for c/java and there are servers available for java at least

Comment: I am sorry to say, but this has to be done only via tcp/ip.

Comment: When you ran the receive code under a debugger, what happened, how far did it get and where did it get stuck?

Comment: The code executed until "Data not written into the file" and then the "Text received" statement was shown. And moreover all buffer size values were displayed in negative numbers.

Comment: And moreover before it printed 'Data not written into the file' it printed an error message which you haven't told us about; and moreover it only printed that message because of an error *reading the socket,* which has nothing to do with the file whatsoever, which means your error message is lying to you. Really this code is a disaster.

Comment: Can you kindly say what is the way that i can get the required output.

Comment: @venkat Can you kindly read what I've already written here, at great length, which already tells you exactly that. You've completely ignored 95% of it. I can therefore have no confidence that anything else I say here will sink in.

Answer (score 5):

This is very poor quality code.

Send loop:

```
do
{
    stat = send(socket, send_buffer, read_size, 0);
    printf("The send size value is: %d \n", size);
    gets(a);
    printf("The read size value is: %d \n", read_size);
    gets(a);
} while (stat < 0);
```

- The 'send size value' is not `size`, it is `stat`
- repeating this loop while there is an error is senseless.
- *not* repeating it while all the data hasn't been sent is also senseless, unless the socket is blocking and there have been no interrupts, which you aren't testing for. A more correct version would be:

  ```
  do
  {
      stat = send(socket, send_buffer, read_size, 0);
      printf("The send size value is: %d \n", stat);
      if (stat > 0)
      {
          send_buffer += stat;
          read_size -= stat;
      }
  } while (stat < 0 && errno == EINTR);
  ```

Receive loop:

```
while(read_size > 0)
{
    ioctl(socket, FIONREAD, &buffersize);
    printf("The Buffersize is    :%d\n",buffersize);
```

The buffersize is `sizeof buffer` at this point. The *number of bytes available to be read without blocking`is given by`buffersize`, *if and only if*`ioctl()` returned zero.

```
    printf("The size of socket is:%d\n",socket);
```

There is no such thing as 'the size of the socket'. Remove.

```
       // We check to see if there is data to be read from the socket
```

Why? What else are you going to do? Remove this entire test, and the `ioctl()`, and just block in `recv()` below.

```
       if (buffersize > 0)
        {
           printf("Buffersize value is  :%d\n", buffersize);
```

You've already printed this. Remove.

```
           pBuf = malloc(buffersize);
```

This is a waste of time and space. Use a fixed-size buffer and allocate it before the loop starts. Remove this.

```
    read_size = recv(socket, pBuf, buffersize, 0);
    printf("Read size value is :%d \n",read_size);
    printf("Buffersize value is:%d \n",pBuf);
```

`pBuf` is not the 'buffersize value`, it is the address of the buffer, and printing it is pointless. Remove this.

```
             if (read_size < 0)
             {
                 printf("%d\n",strerror(errno));
                 printf("Data not written to the file:\n");
                 gets(a);
                 goto free;
             }
```

Here you are missing a test for `read_size == 0`, which indicates end of stream, whereupon you should close the socket and exit the loop.

```
              printf("Buffer size value is  :%d \n",buffersize);
```

Third time you've printed this value, which hasn't changed, and fourth time you've printed this message, once with a bogus value. Remove this.

This whole loop, including the bogus `ioctl()` and test, and the `malloc()` and `free()`, can be reduced to:

```
int read_size;
char buffer[8192];
while ((read_size = recv(socket, buffer, sizeof buffer, 0)) > 0)
{
    fwrite(pBuf, 1, read_size, text); // plus error handling ...
}
if (read_size < 0)
    // print the error as you are doing.
```

Your Java code is equally flaky. I won't comment in detail but it can all be reduced to this:

```
int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray)) > 0)
{
    fos.write(mybytearray, 0, bytesRead);
}
```

Until all this is fixed, at both ends, this will never work.

Comment: I have modified the code as per you said, but in the receive function after the buffer size value is printed, i am getting some numbers in negative and "Data not written to file" is shown and connection is terminated.

Comment: You'll have to post the current code. I'm not interested in guessing games. And when you get an exception, print the exception, not some inane messsage of your own devising. It tells us, and you, precisely nothing about why it occurred.

Comment: @venkat  Note - post you current, partially-fixed code as an apppended section, edited in at the end of your question above, or in a new question.  In either case, do your diligent debugging first.

Comment: @venkat You haven't done any such thing as modifying the code as per what I said. Have you even read this answer? Your 'current code' doesn't bear any relationship to what I posted: it still contains most of the garbage I have already commented on above; and there's no evidence yet that you're done anything about the garbage Java code at all. I cannot help you if you won't  help yourself.

Comment: @EJP I have modified as you said in the receive function, and i kindly request you to be more specific on C rather than Java, because i am doing the C code and there is an other programmer for Java. For one more instance can you give the whole receive code in a function for my better understanding.

Comment: ^^ I just knew it would get round to that:(  Even if @EJP supplies some code with all his fixes in, you will complain again that thre are problems because of the peer issues that you, aparrently, have no control over:(    This whole question thread is tottering dangerously towards 'do all my work for me':((

Comment: @venkat No. When you can't even cut and paste accurately, let alone remove everything I've commented on adversely, and when you can't even see that for yourself, what would be the point? I've already told you everything any competent programmer should need. Further effort on my part would clearly be a complete waste of everybody's time. I don't care about your time, but mine is valuable, and I've already put in my quota here. I can only suggest you re-read this answer, word by word, and act on everything it says. Not just mistype a small piece of it into the middle of your code.

Comment: @EJP, i have modified the code according to what you have said, but still i am the data is not written into the file. cold you kindly guide me

Comment: @EJP. I have modified the code according to the comments, but still i am not able to see data written into the file. Guide me in resolving this issue.

Comment: @venkat No you haven't. You've just made a bigger mess, and left in most of the garbage I commented on, and introduced new errors, and left the other garbage code in there but commented out, which makes the whole thing unreadable. Nobody can help you while you frick around like this.

Comment: @EJP okay i understand, but could you kindly give me the receive function code in a single shot, so that i can resolve my issue, because i am totally struck

Comment: I've answered that, and your question. It's already there above. You're just asking me to repeat myself. I have no belief whatsoever that anything I could tell you would be the slightest use, and I don't propose to waste another second of my valuable time on it. Just try re-reading this answer.